# Signs in the tensor product and internal hom of chain complexes

Tags: intuition, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $\text{Ch}(R)$ the category of chain complexes of $R$-modules. $\text{Ch}(R)$ is first of all an abelian category, but it can also be equipped with the structure of a (symmetric?) closed monoidal category: it has

- a tensor product $A \otimes B$ whose component in degree $n$ is $\bigoplus_{i+j=n} A_i \otimes_R B_j$ and where the differential is defined by $d(a \otimes b) = da \otimes b + (-1)^{|a|} a \otimes db$, and
- an internal hom $\text{hom}(A, B)$ whose component in degree $n$ is $\prod_i \text{Hom}_R(A_i, B_{i+n})$ and where the differential is defined by $(df)(a) = d(fa) - (-1)^{|f|} f(da)$

which are related via the adjunction $\text{Hom}(A \otimes B, C) \cong \text{Hom}(A, \text{hom}(B, C))$.

> How can I motivate the sign convention in either of these definitions?

I can sort of answer that question: both sign conventions are just the graded Leibniz rule. As Theo Johnson-Freyd explains [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59357/why-chain-homotopy-when-there-is-no-topology-in-the-background/59374#59374), this is because $\text{Ch}(R)$ is precisely the category of modules over a one-dimensional graded-commutative Lie algebra over $R$ concentrated in degree $1$. But this is unsatisfying because I don't know the answer to *this* question:

> What do graded Lie algebras have to do with the topological motivation for studying chain complexes?

By "the topological motivation" I mean the idea, made precise by the [Dold-Kan correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dold-Kan+correspondence), that a chain complex is, roughly speaking, a linearization of a combinatorialization of a topological space. I think that the sign convention for the tensor product can be motivated by thinking about simplicial chains, but this doesn't have quite the air of inevitability that I would like out of so fundamental a definition.

I have the feeling that everything goes back to Euler characteristic. A bounded complex can be sent to an alternating sum of elements of $K_0(R)$, and this sum is invariant under chain homotopy and additive in short exact sequences and possibly satisfies a universal property of some kind, and it clearly shows there is a real distinction to be made between the even and odd elements of a chain complex. But I don't know the conceptual route from this idea to the graded Leibniz rule.

Comment: See also [this MO-thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53315/references-for-sign-conventions-in-homological-algebra).

Comment: @Theo: I've seen that thread, but it seems to be discussing more confusing sign conventions than the one I am trying to motivate. In Tyler Lawson's linked notes he claims that the sign convention above follows directly from the symmetric monoidal structure, but I still don't understand why $a \otimes b \mapsto (-1)^{|a| |b|} b \otimes a$ is a natural convention in this context. (I could convince myself that this is a _good idea_ using the de Rham complex or simplicial chains, but I feel like there has to be a more fundamental reason than that.)

Comment: I think [Boardman's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-40740) Peter May mentions in that thread motivates this to a certain extent (in case you're wondering: you can download the paper as a pdf by clicking on the icon next to the title -- it took me a while to figure this out on that page). Of course, you're still left with wondering why the involution $-1$ should be the right one to look at and, more importantly, why you should want to consider dimension as grading modulo $2$, but still it seems like a step in the right direction.

Comment: About the $\mod 2$ thing: one can also consider other values of $2$! Searching arXiv for «$N$-complex» will bring up information about complexes where $d^N$ is zero and not the square: in that context you of course (?) use other roots of unity and not $-1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One algebraic way to motivate this is to observe that the signs in the differential for the Hom are precisely what is needed for 0-cycles in the $\hom(A,B)$ complex to be the set of morphisms of complexes $A\to B$ (and also, that the 0th homology group $H_0(\hom(A,B))$ is the set of homotopy classes of morphisms $A\to B$). This is quite great.

Once you decide you want this, *all* the other signs you mention follow because you need various things to hold. For example, you want the adjuntion between $\hom$ and $\otimes$ to hold for the internal versions, so this forces you to add signs to the $\otimes$, and so on.

A topological, indirect explanation for the appearence of most signs is that in the long exact sequence of bases maps corresponding to a map $f:X\to Y$, which looks like
$$X\to Y\to C(f)\to S(X) \to S(Y) \to S(C(f)) \to \cdots$$ there is a "sign" which you cannot get rid of. This sign reproduces itself in every algebraic version.

Comment: Of course I agree but I have a very silly question: Do you have a good explanation *why* I would want to decide I want this? In other words: How do you motivate the leap from morphisms to $0$-cycles or homotopy classes?

Comment: @Theo: When the complexes are projective resolutions of modules over a ring, you want the homology in degree zero to be $Ext^0$, which is the $\hom$ between the modules. One can probaby flesh this into a motivation :)

Comment: @Theo: if one thinks of chain complexes as algebraic analogues of topological spaces and internal hom as an algebraic analogue of the internal hom in a nice category of topological spaces, then $0$-cycles are analogues of points and $1$-cycles are analogues of homotopies between points, so a $0$-cycle in the internal hom is a continuous map and a $0$-cycle up to boundaries is a homotopy class of continuous maps.

Comment: this is precisely my reason for caring about the internal hom, but it feels like putting the cart before the horse. I feel like there should be a natural reason this all falls out of the definition of the category of chain complexes and I don't know what that reason is. Can you explain that last paragraph a little more? I'm not sure I know what the notation in it means.

Comment: Dear Mariano, I hope you don't mind that I edited your LaTeX.  Best wishes,

Comment: Mariano, can you elaborate on the "signs" that show up in the long exact sequence? Or tell me where I might find it in reference material?

Comment: @eric, the sequence is the so called Puppe sequence. If you look up its construction, you'll see that one of the maps involves a reversal of orientation (you construct the suspension of something in an indirect way, which gives you the space "upside down")