# The internal hom in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Ab})$ as a coproduct?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

The internal hom in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Ab})$ is defined grading-wise by $$(A\Rightarrow B)_n=\prod_{i\in \mathbb Z} \text{Hom}_R(A_i, B_{i+n})$$

Intuitively, I would have defined the internal hom as $$(A\Rightarrow B)_n=\coprod_{i\in \mathbb Z} \text{Hom}_R(A_i, B_{i+n})$$ since I merely want to "collect" the degree $n$ arrows, and in $\mathsf{Set}$, it seems coproducts are more suitable for that. I don't understand why products pop up.

For finite (co)products, this would make no difference since $\mathsf{Ab}$ is abelian, which is nice, but no longer true for infinite (co)products.

- Why, intuitively, is the internal hom defined via products and not
  coproducts?
- How does the tensor-hom adjunction determine products rather than coproducts?
- What would the tensor product be if we defined the internal hom with coproducts?

Comment: Intuitively, internal homs are a kind of limit. Think, for example, of the internal hom of sets: $A \Rightarrow B$ can be thought of as the product of the trivial $A$-indexed family of copies of $B$. Dually, tensor products are a kind of colimit: $A \times B$ can be thought of as the coproduct of the trivial $A$-indexed family of copies of $B$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that's a helpful bit of intuition. I've been looking at [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40468/signs-in-the-tensor-product-and-internal-hom-of-chain-complexes) - have you found convincing motivation for the sign conventions?

Comment: I know more things relevant to that question than I do now, but I haven't written down a single satisfying story yet.

Comment: One thing remember is that internal homs aka exponential objects have a more general definition that apply to all categories (that have them.)

Comment: @PyRulez you mean closed categories? Do you have a recommended reference for those?

Comment: @Exterior http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object, also look it up on nlab, which includes slightly more general definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal hom is defined via maps *into* it. You know nothing about the classification of maps into a coproduct, but you know how to classify the maps into a product, by the very definition of a product.

You can also see how the product comes up in the following calculation:

Let $A,B,C$ be graded $R$-modules (the case of chain complexes is similar, but with added differentials). Then the internal hom $\underline{\hom}(B,C)$ should satisfy by definition
$$\hom(A \otimes B , C) \cong \hom(A,\underline{\hom}(B,C)).$$
Now let $A$ be $R$ concentrated in degree $n$. Then the right hand side identifies with $\underline{\hom}(B,C)_n$, whereas the left hand side is $\hom(B[-n],C)$, which identifies with $\prod_i \hom(B_{i},C_{i+n})$ by the definiton of morphisms of graded modules.

Although $[B,C] := \bigoplus_i \hom(B_i,C_{i+n})$ defines a closed structure, it is not induced by a tensor product, since $[-,C]$ is not continuous.